# to save data from a modal without page reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to save data passed through a modal into database without reloading the page.But I don't know what is wrong with my code,It is not functioning properly.
Here is my code,Kindly let me know if you find out where i went wrong.
modal code-

```
<div id="mypartymodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:1000px;">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>  New Party Entry</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form  class="partyform"  id="partyform">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Party name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="party_name" name="party_name" >
      </div>
    </div>
 <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Opening bal:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="op_bal" name="op_bal" placeholder="Op.bal">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Vat:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="vat" name="vat" placeholder="Vat no.">
      </div>
    </div>

 <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Cst:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cst" name="cst" placeholder="Cst no.">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Pan:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pan" name="pan" placeholder="Pan no.">
      </div>
    </div>


     <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Service Tax no.:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ser" name="ser" placeholder="Service Tax no.">
      </div>
      <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Address:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Enter address"></textarea>
      </div>

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">

     <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Email-id:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter email-id">
      </div>
       <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Mobile:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mob" name="mob" placeholder="Enter contact number">
      </div>
    </div>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" id="saveparty" name="saveparty" value="Save" />

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

script-

```
$("#saveparty").click(function(){
         $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
 url: "party_post.php",
 data: $('form.partyform').serialize(),
         success: function(msg){
                 alert(msg);
        $("#mypartymodal").modal('hide'); 
         },
 error: function(){
 alert("failure");
 }
       });
 });
```

party_post.php code-

```
<?php
include('db.php');
if(isset($_POST['saveparty'])){
    $name = $_POST['party_name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];
$group = 'Sundry Creditor';
$op_bal = $_POST['op_bal'];
$vat = $_POST['vat'];
$cst = $_POST['cst'];
$pan = $_POST['pan'];
$ser = $_POST['ser'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$mob = $_POST['mob'];
$sql ="INSERT INTO `master` (`ledger_name`, `ledger_grp`, `tally_grp`, `address`, `op_bal`, `cl_bal`, `vat`, `cst`, `ser_tax`, `email`, `tel`) 
VALUES ('$name', '$group', '$group', '$address', '$op_bal', '0.00', '$vat', '$cst', '$ser', '$email', '$mob')";

if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){

    echo "saved";
}
else{
    echo "failed";
}
}
else{
    echo "not done";
}


?>
```

Please let me know if you need any other information regarding the code.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery's serialize() is NOT serializing buttons or submit inputs in it's result so your submitted data will not contain saveparty property

Change your data to something like

```
    $("#saveparty").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

       formData = $('form.partyform').serialize() + '&' 
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('name'))
        + '='
        + encodeURI($(this).attr('value'));

             $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "party_post.php",
               data: formData,
               success: function(msg){
                     alert(msg);
                   $("#mypartymodal").modal('hide'); 
                },
               error: function(){
                alert("failure");
               }
           });
     });
```

Note from the jquery's [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) api

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. No submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted using a button. For a form element's value to be included in the serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox") are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Comment: but can i just know why it was not serializing before..I mean ,i have tried that code before and it worked at that time..

Comment: @payal_suthar as jquery api mentionned the submit buttons aren't considered to be "successful controls"

Answer (score 0):

You didn't prevent default action of your input. in your jquery code you can do like this:

```
$("#saveparty").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
         $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
 url: "party_post.php",
 data: $('form.partyform').serialize(),
         success: function(msg){
                 alert(msg);
        $("#mypartymodal").modal('hide'); 
         },
 error: function(){
 alert("failure");
 }
       });
 });
```

Comment: nope ....not helping ..still getting the same msg in alert..i.e...not done

Comment: what is the alert msg

Comment: not done..it is echoing the third msg from party_post.php @safinchacko

Comment: Can you dump " isset($_POST['saveparty']) " in you php code?
  `event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );`

Answer (score 0):

try  `data: $('#partyform').serialize(),`

also put form inside modal-body (check open and close of div correctly)

```
<div class="modal-body">

<form.....>    
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: still the same...I guess it is being prevent at the `if(isset("saveparty"))` itself..that's the reason i am getting that msg in alert.